# Event Listeners only working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, responsive, addeventlistener

I know there are a few similar questions but I have waded through them without any luck.
My event listeners (both "click") work great, but only once, after a page refresh. It is just code to slide the hidden nav menu out for a mobile device screen.

Here is the JS code:

```
/*Menu responsive code*/
const hamburger = document.getElementById('menuIcon');
const closeMenu = document.getElementById('closeNav');
const navUL = document.getElementById('navUL');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navUL.classList.toggle('show');
});


closeMenu.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navUL.classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

Again, this problem has to do with the javascript, not the CSS/HTML since it works great that one time (unless I am completely wrong). Also new to javascript.

hamburger and closeMenu are my ionicons used/the buttons. the show and hidden classes just translateX between 0% and 100%.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when they fail?

Comment: Why do you have two different classes, `show` and `hidden`? Shouldn't there just be one class that you toggle on and off?

Comment: Why are you toggling two distinct classes that have the opposite meaning of each other? Either `show` should be toggled, or `hidden`, but not both. Why does the close button _toggle_ the `hidden` class instead of adding it, or removing the `show` class?

Comment: The problem probably arises when both classes are added to the element.

Comment: @Barmar no there are no console errors.

Comment: that was it guys, totally didn't think about that being weird. thanks!

Comment: ok, so now i only have one problem left, it automatically toggles when i load the page. and i've been trying to get it to not do that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case with 2 classes you should remove the other class when you are adding the new one.

if you are using only one class you can use toogle but with 2 classes yo have to use add and remove together.
exemple here :

```
const hamburger = document.getElementById('menuIcon');
const closeMenu = document.getElementById('closeNav');
const navUL = document.getElementById('navUL');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navUL.classList.add('red');
     navUL.classList.remove('blue');
});


closeMenu.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      navUL.classList.add('blue');
      navUL.classList.remove('red');
})
```

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111